# Setting value of one class from another class

Tags: objective-c

**ClassA.m**

```
ClassB *CB = [[ClassB alloc]init];
CB.name = @"my name";
[self presentViewController:CB animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**ClassB.h**

```
@interface ClassBViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

This code works fine but setting value in ClassB from ClassA `CB.name = @"my name";` is a correct approach?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Did some problem result? If so, please describe what happened.

Comment: Unless you have a really good reason to do something else, you should **copy** instances of classes that have mutable/immutable variations.

Comment: @JodyHagins please describe in bit detail, thank you.

Comment: By defining your attribute as **strong** you are keeping a strong reference to the object.  Consider what happens if someone gives you a `NSMutableString`.  You keep a reference to it, and then they change it later.  You no longer have the string they gave you.  If you use **copy** instead of **strong** you force a copy of the object (which is usually optimized away if they give you an immutable object) which means you always keep what you were actually given.

Comment: @JodyHagins Please write this in an answer so I can vote and select as correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Whoever down vote my question please read Jody Hagins reply, I was confused regarding the concept not the syntax and Jody Hagins post a perfect reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining your attribute as strong you are keeping a strong reference to the object.

Consider what happens if someone gives you a `NSMutableString`. You keep a reference to it, and then they change it later. You no longer have the string they gave you.

If you use **copy** instead of **strong** you force a copy of the object (which is usually optimized away if they give you an immutable object) which means you always keep what you were actually given.

Answer (score 0):

For properties, I find it clearer to write [CB setName:@"my name"]. You need a @synthesize statement in your ClassB.m file so the compiler will make a getter and a setter for your property.

Comment: You do _not_ need an `@synthesize` in any of the most recent several versions of Clang.

Comment: True, should have said you *may* need... old habits die hard.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually the only approach. `Class A` doesn't know anything about the properties of `Class B`, so  an object of `Class B` must be instantiated inside of `Class A` to have access to its properties.